# one to one relationship in SQL Modeler

Tags: oracle, database-design, foreign-key, oracle-sql-developer

**USING ORACLE SQL MODELER**

I am trying to make Relationship between 2 entities (`Roles` and `Users`). The `Users` table has `role_id` as a foreign key. The Relationship between Roles(1) and Users(Many) is `1:N`, so when I do this on Data Modeler:
[image]

The relation should be fine. however when I engineer the logical model to relation model, somehow the reverse happens, and `Roles` table gets `user_id` foreign key:
[image]

and when I reverse the relation Roles(Many) and Users(1), only then I get the foreign key `role_id` in `Users` table.

Can Somebody help?

Comment: You appear to have your cardinality defined backwards. Source (Users) to Target (Roles) should be one, and Target to Source should be many.

Comment: @pmdba, I have already mentioned that when I reverse the cardinality, the issue fixes, however the logic of users(1) to Roles(Many) is reversed...

Comment: You are reading the fields backwards. You say you want Roles to Users as 1:N but your screenshot shows the opposite. It's showing Users:Roles (source-to-target) as 1:N and Roles:Users (target:source) as 1:1. Set the Target Key to Role.ID and reverse the cardinality.

Comment: Thanks!. @pmdba